# Failed to run SQL: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Help with Failed to run SQL: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

What does the error mean?
I am new to MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admins` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `setpass_3010` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

So could anyone help with the problem?
I think problem is here some where!

Comment: I think problem is in your insert command. In your insert command don't try to insert ID. It set as auto increment.

Answer (score 2):

When inserting data to this table you shouldn't fill `id` column at all. It's set as `auto increment` so value will be set automatically.  The error means that you cannot have 2 records with the same `id` because you probably insert 2 or more records with the same id and you cannot do this.